# Redirect loop when changing the url with Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to create a small script that redirects users to the correct page based on their country. However, I keep getting a redirect loop...

The logic I am looking for is that if the URL contains /de/ but the page is /distro-uk then redirect to /distro-de if the URL is /de/ and the page is distro-de then do nothing...

Thank you in advance!

```
<script>
var string= location.href;
var convertedString= string.toLowerCase();


// Germany
if ((convertedString.indexOf('/de/') != -1) || (convertedString.indexOf('distro-de') === -1)) {
    window.location.href = '/de/pages/distro-de';

// France
} else if ((convertedString.indexOf('/fr/') != -1) || (convertedString.indexOf('/distro-fr') === -1)) {
    window.location.href = '/fr/pages/distro-fr';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your first if will always pass for `de` pages and redirect to `de` page again infinitely

Comment: I would rather add an .htaccess file for this, you can define such rules in it.

Comment: I figured it out, I should be using &&. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have been using && rather than ||